# Generating .resx resource files in the correct encoding

Tags: visual-studio-2017-build-tools, resgen

I know I can change a resource file's encoding in the Properties tool window (e.g. to Unicode/utf-16), but this only sets the it for the existing file.

Can I get Visual Studio's Resource Generator (resgen.exe) to output files of a specific encoding in the first place, so that I don't need to change the encoding type every time I add, remove or update an entry in the file using the resource editor, or do I need to add a pre-build event command in the project properties?

Comment: Likely to be an XY problem.  Just make sure that whatever you embed as a resource is encoded as expected.

Comment: @HansPassant An XY problem? I'd like the file to be Unicode-encoded so that I can include characters outside of utf-8's range.

Comment: It already is, there is no such thing as "outside of utf-8's range".  Utf-8 does not skip anything, it is capable of representing all possible codepoints.  So that is not your real problem.  The only thing you care about is what the resource looks like when it pops out in your program.  What comes out is what goes in, neither the VS resource designer nor .resx nor resgen.exe change that.  What goes in is commonly not encoded correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was over-complicating matters, I opted to use the [UTF-16-to-UTF-8 character converter](https://onlineutf8tools.com/convert-utf16-to-utf8) instead.

This seems to be enough for my needs.